# how to convert a pdf with the format to xls in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to convert this pdf page [this is the pdf screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CgFc.jpg) to .xls file along with the columns.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you want to convert only "this" pdf? just copy the values. :-)

Comment: No this is a sample and i just want to convert this kind of pdf to xls with the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a PDF parsing library to extract the text. This could be very easy to impossible. It depends on how the table is represented internally. If it is represented as an image you will also need an OCR library. In the easiest case you could just extract all the text as a string and split rows according to newlines and columns according to tabs or other whitespace.

Try this one and see what happens: http://www.squarepdf.net/parsing-pdf-files-using-itextsharp

Edit: I focused on the reading the PDF part. The writing to Excel is more than covered with a quick google search.

Comment: the image is a sample and i just want to convert that kind of pdf to xls with the columns.

Comment: Yep my answer should cover that case. Are these PDFs all generally different, e.g. you want to solve the general case of PDFs with tables of numbers in them created by different programs, or can you assume that this is like some standard report always generated by the same program. A completely general solution will of course be harder than a specific one but my answer should be a good starting point.